# Netbeans IDE code template on selected text

Tags: netbeans, yii2, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins, code-templates

In [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) framework and other PHP frameworks, there is a translation function used for [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n). I'm using [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) IDE and I have created the following code template:

```
Yii::t('app', ${selection})${cursor}
```

The abbreviation for the above code template is `yiit`. The purpose of this template is to making easy selecting a text in the code and wrap it in the translation function. Suppose the following:

```
<?=Html::a('Home',['site/index']);?>
```

So, when selecting `'Home'` and **applying the code template** it should replac the `'Home'` with: `Yii::t('app', 'Home')`

The problem in **applying the code template** there is no any way to call the code template other than writing its abbreviation, `yiit` followed by `Tab` and of course this delete the selected text `'Home'` and the result is the code template with empty replacement string `Yii::t('app', )`.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. It is macro. 
`Tools->Options->Editor tab->Macros tab`
Then click `New` give the new Macro a name, I named it `Yii Translate` then enter the following code into Macro Code:

```
cut-to-clipboard "Yii::t('app'," paste-from-clipboard ")"
```

Click Apply, then press Set Shortcut button to make an initiator keyboard shortcut, I set it to be `Alt+NUMPAD0`

Now go to the editor and select any string then press `ALT+NUMPAD0` will cut the string and paste it in the desired code.

For reference [this is a list of Macro codes](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEditorMacros)